# R Markdown Presentation: showing one plot in each slide

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a list of 300 plots and want one PowerPoint slide to show one plot (300 slides). What's the best way to achieve this?

A toy example using the built-in iris dataset to create a list of plots:

```
purrr::map(names(iris[,-5]), function(col_name){
  plot = iris %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = !!as.name(col_name))) + 
    geom_histogram()
  return(plot)
})
```

I hope to create PowerPoint slides with one plot on each slide.

Answer (score 1):

I will be using the `iris` data set, which is a built-in data set often used to populate example code.

With the following code in a Rmd file:

````
---
title: "Test_PowerPoint"
author: "KoenV"
date: '2022-06-30'
output: powerpoint_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r include=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
```

```{r, iris, fig.cap="A scatterplot.", echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}

## your code    
purrr::map(names(iris[,-5]), function(col_name){
  plot = iris %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = !!as.name(col_name))) + 
    geom_histogram()
  return(plot)
})

```
````

And after hitting the "knit" button, you will see a PowerPoint presentation appearing, with the following lay-out:

[image]

Please let me know, whether this is what you wanted.

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of the list item indicators on the left and only show the plots? There is lots of wasted space in your slides. Can we make each plot take up the entire slide so the details of the plot can be seen more easily?

Comment: For those of you still looking for a solution, I ended up using "invisible(capture.output(your_object))" to get rid of the item Indics. I also added  {r out.width='150%',out.height='150%'} to make each plot show up in each slide (not sure why it works).